# How can I select a null value for no colour, from a kendo color picker?

Tags: colors, kendo-ui, picker

I am trying to configure a colour picker for users to select from a set of colours using a palette of Hex strings from the database.  I have it all working fine except I can’t set the value to null for no colour selected.  Leaving the value property out, setting it to null, or an empty string all select the first option in the colour picker.  Does anyone know how I can set a value for no colour selected?

my view:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
        .Name("Colour")
        .TileSize(32)
        .Columns(16)
        .Palette(colours)
        .Deferred()
    )
```

My Controller Method to get the array:

```
public string[] GetColours()
{
     var autoCadColours = _somerService.GetColours();
     int length = autoCadColours.Count();
     string[] colours = new string[length];
     foreach (var i in autoCadColours.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }))
     {
          colours[i.Index] = i.Value.HexString;
     }
     return colours;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve this I used the Change event to set the value using Ajax.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
                            .Name("Color")
                            .Events(e => e.Change("colourChange"))
                            .Value("0") 
                            .TileSize(32)
                            .Columns(16)
                            .Palette(colours)
                            .Deferred()
                    )
```